# Unable to suggest edit

Tags: support, editing

I'm having a problem that from now on I'm not able to suggest edits to the Ask Ubuntu site. I'm pretty sure that the edits I have been made were relevant and I want to know whether some user is able to restrict me from that. Please help!

[image]

Comment: This probably happened because very few of the previous edits you suggested were accepted. I don't know how long this restriction will apply to you if that was indeed the reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several of the edits that you suggested were rejected which lead to your account temporary barred from suggesting any more edits. This suspension would last for a week and is automatic.

See [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled).

---

Just going through some of your recent suggested edits:

- [Edit 205528](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205528) - Too minor. The title could have been improved.
- [Edit 205526](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205526) - Stripped info from title.
- [Edit 205525](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205525) - **Very** minor change which categorically ignored every other issue with the post.
- [Edit 205529](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205529) - The description read 'improved formatting' but the edit clearly had nothing to do with formatting. It only tampered the title.

I am looking at a plethora of suggested edits that don't seem to greatly improve the value of the post, which doesn't bode well with our policy.

Just for your quick reference, here's a relevant quote from the [help center about editing](https://askubuntu.com/help/editing):

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
>   you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

Answer (score 8):

You recently made quite a few edits and most of them were rejected. And as a result, you are temporarily banned from making new edits for [7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192/220538).  Here are some of your rejected edits:

- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205529
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205528
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205526
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205521
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205520
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205519
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205515
- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/205513

You can review all the edits you've made so far in the [Activity Tab](https://askubuntu.com/users/189471/varun-das?tab=activity). Go through them and try to find out what could have caused the  edit to get rejected. Some of these edits change too much of the post and some of them are too minor.

Here are some suggestions:

- **Try to make the improve as much as you can.** Make the post substantially better by addressing multiple issues in the question / answer
- **Try not to change the original meaning of the post.** For example, when you edit the title of a question, the whole question might become different from what the original poster intended it to be

See also:

- [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)