# Why edit option is Off?

Tags: discussion

How many edit can i make in a day , because it has been off for two days ?

I edit in review around 30 questions and now edit is off , why ?

Comment: This Q&A applies to to this question as well ... http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8017/unable-to-suggest-edit/8019#8019

Answer (score 5):

You got a temporary ban against editing due to [previous suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/users/230052/nux?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) being rejected by other community members.

It'll clear automatically in 5 days.